# prevent app from crashing if there is no internet

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app is crashing when there is no internet. This is because

```
NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

returns the error `'data parameter is nil'`.

How can I prevent this from crashing as I am caching the `jsonData` using [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).
 So it should still be there even if there is no internet!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make sure that the code is executed just if the data is not nil:

```
if (jsonData) {
    NSDictionary *result = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                               options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not handle only nil , and not proper format of json too and you can get the error msg for further

```
  @try {

        responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception %@",exception);
    }
```

Comment: please add your comment to the answer - code only answers are discouraged here!